# Universal property of $N\rtimes K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, semidirect-product, universal-property

Given groups $N$ and $K$, if $K$ acts on $N$ by \begin{equation}
K\xrightarrow{\theta}\operatorname{Aut_{Grp}}(N),
\end{equation} then we can define a group $N\rtimes_{\theta}K$ whose elements are like in $N\times K$ but the multiplication is defined by \begin{equation}
(n,k)(n',k')=(n\theta_{k}(n'),kk')
\end{equation} where $\theta_k\in \operatorname{Aut_{Grp}}(N)$ is the image of $k$ under $\theta$.

This semidirect product is very useful in studying structures of finite groups, especially it solves the extension problem \begin{equation}
1\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow N\rtimes_{\theta} K\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow 1.
\end{equation} But I am wondering whether this can be defined using universal properties? In the abelian case $N\rtimes K$ is just $N\times K$ so we have the universal property of products, but what about the nonabelian case?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that $N\rtimes K$ is universal omong all $N\to G\leftarrow K$ where (the image of) $K$ operates on (the image of) $N$ via $\theta$

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96078/are-semi-direct-products-categorical-limits

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of the MSE search engine, I'm summarizing the discussion in [the associated MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96078/are-semi-direct-products-categorical-limits).

First, note that each group can be considered to be [a (relatively simple) category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340993/equivalence-of-group-objects-in-set-and-groups-as-one-object-categories).  If we assume that our semidirect factors $N$ and $K$ are encoded this way, then one can encode $\theta$ as a functor $K\to\textbf{Cat}$ sending $\star\mapsto N$.  Post-encoding, one obtains a nice description of $N\rtimes K$ as a Grothendieck construction/Kan extension $\int^K{N}$.  If you want fancy names, then this describes $N\rtimes K$ as a lax 2-colimit.

Unfortunately, you probably don't just want fancy names: you probably want a description of semidirect products that is element-free.  The encoding process to make a lax 2-colimit construction elevates each element of $N$ and $K$ to a category morphism, which defeats the point.  So can we give an element-free description?

Yes!  Consider the morphism category $\textbf{Mor}(\textbf{Grp})$ which consists of group homomorphisms $A\to B$.  An element $F\in\textbf{Mor}(\textbf{Grp})$ defines a map $A\to\text{Aut}(B)$; elements of $A$ act on $B$ by conjugating by the image under $F$.  There is a forgetful functor dropping the specific map $A\to B$ in favor of the action $A\to\text{Aut}(B)$; the mapping taking $K\to\text{Aut}(N)$ to the inclusion $K\to N\rtimes K$ is the left-adjoint of that forgetful functor.

Both of these options are discussed on [the $n$-CatLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semidirect+product+group).

Lastly, one might object that both of these constructions build the semidirect product as a colimits.  One usually encounters semidirect products are a generalization of direct products, which are limits, so one might hope for a limit construction.  But this is something of a coincidence: the direct product is a quotient of the coproduct (free product) via $$N\times H=N*H/\langle\!\langle nhn^{-1}h^{-1}\rangle\!\rangle_{n\in N, h\in H}$$ where $\langle\!\langle\cdot\rangle\!\rangle$ denotes the [normal closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_closure_(group_theory)) generated by those elements.  A semidirect product is a twist of this quotient via $$N\times H=N*H/\langle\!\langle nhn^{-1}\theta_h(n)^{-1}\rangle\!\rangle_{n\in N, h\in H}$$  Indeed, within the category of groups (or, really, any subcategory of pointed sets), a direct product has both projection and injection maps to and from (respectively) each direct factor.  The projections are what makes it a direct product…and the condition that *semi*direct products choose to weaken.

Answer (score 2):

Since this got bumped already today, I'll add another answer based on Martin Brandenburg's answer in the linked question. The point of this answer is to give a short and to the point answer that's (ideally) a little more transparent to beginners than the other existing answer.

If $\phi:K\to \newcommand\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(N)$, then
$N\rtimes_\phi K$ is universal among groups $G$ with pairs of maps $i : N\to G$ and $j : K\to G$ such that for all $n\in N$, $k\in K$,
$$
j(k)i(n)j(k)^{-1} = i(\phi_k(n)),
$$
where $\phi_k=\phi(k)$,
In the sense that for any such group $G$ there is a unique map $(i,j) : N\rtimes_\phi K \to G$ such that $(i,j)|_N = i$, and $(i,j)|_K = j$.

In words, $N\rtimes_\phi K$ is universal (initial) for groups $G$ with maps from $N$ and $K$ where the image of $K$ is in the normalizer of the image of $N$, the kernel of $N\to G$ is fixed (setwise) by the action of $K$, and the conjugation action of $K$ on the image of $N$ is given by $\phi$.

As discussed in the other answer, despite products being a special case of semidirect products, we only have injection maps and not projections for semidirect products, so they are a kind of colimit.

For other perspectives and more details read [the other answer by Jacob Manaker](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4204494/90543) or the [MO answer by Martin Brandenburg](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96081/69100).